# How to add session value in handler and get the session value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, httphandler

I am using below handler for my file upload functionality. I am uploading files one by one.
i want to add all files in my `List<AttachedFiles>` & then want to pass this list object into jquery. Please let me know,how we can add the list of attached files in session and pass this into jquery.

```
public class FUploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    List<AttachedFiles> test = new List<AttachedFiles>();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {        
        var headers = context.Request.Headers;
        string[] files;
        string fileName = string.Empty;

        var file = context.Request.Files[i];
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")
        {
            files = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            fileName = files[files.Length - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = file.FileName;
        }

        if (file.ContentLength >= 0)
        {
            file.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\" + fileName);
            string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            test.Add(new AttachedFiles
                {
                    ShowFName = fullName,
                    FSize = file.ContentLength
                });
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonObj = js.Serialize(test);                
    }
}

class AttachedFiles
{
     string _FileName;
     int _fileSize;

     public string ShowFName
     {
         get { return _FileName; }
         set { _FileName = value; }
     }

     public int FSize
     {
         get { return _fileSize; }
         set { _fileSize = value; }
     }
}
```

Comment: You could make an AJAX call to a method and return it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass objects from server side to the client side, you must consider using page methods which allows you to call a C# (server side function) from jqueryAjax(client side). You can then return your object to the jquery function and make use if the object in jquery.